# How to read xml file in java

Tags: java, xml

How to read XML file in java.

Below is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LivescoreData>
  <Sport SportId="1">
    <Name language="en">Soccer</Name>
    <Name language="se">Fotboll</Name>
    <Category CategoryId="34">
      <Name language="en">Australia</Name>
      <Name language="se">Australien</Name>
      <Tournament TournamentId="144">
        <Name language="en">Hyundai A-League</Name>
        <Name language="se">Hyundai A-League</Name>
        <Match MatchId="4616735">
          <MatchDate>2011-01-05T07:30:00</MatchDate>
          <Team1 TeamId="1029369">
            <Name language="en">Wellington Phoenix FC</Name>
            <Name language="se">Wellington</Name>
          </Team1>
          <Team2 TeamId="529088">
            <Name language="en">Melbourne Victory</Name>
            <Name language="se">Melbourne Victory</Name>
          </Team2>
          <Status Code="100">
            <Name language="en">Ended</Name>
            <Name language="se">Avslutad</Name>
          </Status>
          <Winner>1</Winner>
          <Scores>
            <Score type="Current">
              <Team1>2</Team1>
              <Team2>0</Team2>
            </Score>
          </Scores>
          <Goals></Goals>
          <Cards></Cards>
          <Substitutions></Substitutions>
          <Lineups></Lineups>
        </Match>
      </Tournament>
    </Category>
    <Category CategoryId="1">
      <Name language="en">England</Name>
      <Name language="se">England</Name>
      <Tournament TournamentId="1">
        <Name language="en">Premier League</Name>
        <Name language="se">Premier League</Name>
        <Match MatchId="4601857">
          <MatchDate>2011-01-04T21:00:00</MatchDate>
          <Team1 TeamId="5431228">
            <Name language="en">Blackpool FC</Name>
            <Name language="se">Blackpool FC</Name>
          </Team1>
          <Team2 TeamId="23960">
            <Name language="en">Birmingham City</Name>
            <Name language="se">Birmingham City</Name>
          </Team2>
          <Status Code="100">
            <Name language="en">Ended</Name>
            <Name language="se">Avslutad</Name>
          </Status>
          <Winner>1</Winner>
          <Scores>
            <Score type="Current">
              <Team1>5</Team1>
              <Team2>1</Team2>
            </Score>
          </Scores>
          <Goals></Goals>
          <Cards></Cards>
          <Substitutions></Substitutions>
          <Lineups></Lineups>
        </Match>
        <Match MatchId="4601859">
          <MatchDate>2011-01-04T21:00:00</MatchDate>
          <Team1 TeamId="26511">
            <Name language="en">Fulham FC</Name>
            <Name language="se">Fulham FC</Name>
          </Team1>
          <Team2 TeamId="94356">
            <Name language="en">West Bromwich Albion</Name>
            <Name language="se">West Bromwich Albion</Name>
          </Team2>
          <Status Code="100">
            <Name language="en">Ended</Name>
            <Name language="se">Avslutad</Name>
          </Status>
          <Winner>1</Winner>
          <Scores>
            <Score type="Current">
              <Team1>4</Team1>
              <Team2>1</Team2>
            </Score>
          </Scores>
          <Goals></Goals>
          <Cards></Cards>
          <Substitutions></Substitutions>
          <Lineups></Lineups>
        </Match>
      </Tournament>
    </Category>
  </Sport>
</LivescoreData>
```

Below is the code:IT print the first value of XML Soccer and not able to print the next one.

```
nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("Sport"); 
for (int i = 0; i < nodeLst.getLength(); i++) { 

    Node myNode = nodeLst.item(i); 

    if (myNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 

       Element Sport = (Element) myNode; 
       NodeList Name= Sport 
        .getElementsByTagName("Name"); 
       Element NameElement = (Element) Name.item(0); 
       NodeList Namevalue = NameElement.getChildNodes(); 
       System.out.println("Name : " 
    + ((Node) Namevalue.item(0)).getNodeValue()+"|");  

    //This gives me null value  
       NodeList Category = Sport 
       .getElementsByTagName("Category"); 
       Element CategoryName= (Element) Category 
       .item(0); 
       NodeList Categoryvalue = CategoryName 
       .getChildNodes(); 
       System.out.println("Category: " 
       + ((Node) Categoryvalue.item(0)) 
       .getNodeValue()); 
   } 
}
```

Am able to read only the first data Soccer.The second one just give null value.

I need my result as:

```
Soccer | Australia | Hyundai A-League | Wellington Phoenix FC - Melbourne Victory : 2 - 0
Soccer | England | Premier League | Blackpool FC - Birmingham City : 5 - 1
Soccer | England | Premier League | Fulham FC - West Bromwich Albion : 4 - 1
```

Comment: for start, you can read [this tutorial](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html) explain can read xml in java...

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't really said what you want to do with said XML file, the best I can do is direct you to this guide:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/dom.html

Comment: hello,thanks for the reply.Below is my code.Am able to fetch the values first tag  Name : Soccer|  But am getting null values in the next tag.Can you please help me how to do that?

Comment: @user1230541 You can edit your question to add extra information

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jaxp/ReleaseNotes_160.html) for parsing the XML

Answer (score 0):

It's much better/easier NOT to do this in Java, but to do it in XSLT or XQuery code which you can invoke from your Java application.

Answer (score 0):

Search keyword: 644264426442
The code include how to write and read .xml in java

save:

```
List<Node> list = tree.levelTraversal();
File file = new File("people.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
try {
    DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
    Element root= document.createElement("people");
    document.appendChild(root);
    for(Node n:list){
       Person p = (Person) n.getData();
       Element person = document.createElement("person");
       root.appendChild(person);
       Element id = document.createElement("id");
       id.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p.getId().toString()));
       person.appendChild(id);
       Element name = document.createElement("name");
       name.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p.getName()));
       person.appendChild(name);
       Element age = document.createElement("age");
       age.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p.getAge().toString()));
       person.appendChild(age);    
       Element occupation = document.createElement("occupation");
       occupation.appendChild(document.createTextNode(p.getOccupation()));
       person.appendChild(occupation);
    }
    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newDefaultInstance().newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    DOMSource domSource=new DOMSource(document);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
    transformer.transform(domSource,result);
}
//==========================================
Element root = doc.createElement(STATE_ROOT_ELEMENT);
doc.appendChild(root);
for(int i=0;i< keys.size();i++){
    Element key = doc.createElement(keys.get(i));
    key.setTextContent(states.get(i));
    root.appendChild(key);
    }
```

load:

```
File f = new File(FileUtil.getTableFileName(tableName));
DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(f);
NodeList customersList = document.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ELEMENT);
for(int i =0; i<customersList.getLength();i++){
Customer customer = new Customer();
Element element = (Element) customersList.item(i);
Integer id = null;
if(element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ID).getLength()!=0)
    id = Integer.valueOf(element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_ID).item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
if(element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME).getLength()!=0)
    name = element.getElementsByTagName(Customer.KEY_NAME).item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
//=====================
NodeList list = doc.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
for(int i =0;i<list.getLength();i++){
    if(list.item(i).getNodeType()==1) {
        String s1 = list.item(i).getNodeName();
        key.add(s1);
        String s2 = list.item(i).getTextContent();
        states.add(s2);
    }
}
returnList.add(key);
returnList.add(states);
return returnList;
```

Test

```
@Test(expected = NullCharacterException.class, timeout = 1000)
public void testNullCharacterException() {
    State state = StandState.getInstance();
    state.check(null,Key.RESET);
}
//=========================================================
@Test
public void test2(){
    Person person = new Person("jake",30,"1",false,false);
    person.setId(1);
    Exception exception = assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, ()->{
        personRepository.save(person);
    });;
    assertEquals("Person instance must have null id",exception.getMessage());
}
```